# Disable Automatic Magnification on Windows 8 Touchscreen Laptop with Chrome

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, touchscreen

I have a touchscreen Windows 8 laptop (an Ultrabook).

When surfing the web with Google Chrome it very often tries to be helpful by magnifying part of the screen that I touch, perhaps because I'm touching near multiple active parts of a website.

I really want to disable this. It's been driving me crazy for months.

I've done a lot of searching online to try to figure out how, but the results I get are always related to either pinch-and-zoom (which I like), accessibility (this is NOT that magnifier, it's disabled), or touchpads.

I'm not sure if this is a feature of Chrome or Windows 8. I have no significant 3rd party software installed. While the Windows 8 installation originally came from the manufacturer, after messing up the MBR by trying to dual boot linux a PC repair shop installed a generic copy of Win 8 (I think) and this annoying feature was there both before and after.

Comment: This affliction has hit me too. Have you discovered the secret of this blight? I narrowed a behavior like this down to the latest version of Google Chrome 39.0.2171.65 m.

Comment: @RobertP I haven't figured it out yet, but I think that I will try to reach out to some Chrome/Chromium dev's this evening and I will report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're not alone.  This chrome bug is driving many people crazy.  See link...

https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chrome/Qw5D5n6cJA4

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Yes, I also got some emails from other people affected by this. I am going to try to explore the source code of Chrome (i.e. Chromium, the open source version) by this weekend if no one has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you force an update by visiting chrome://help/ and you are updated to 39.0.2171.71, the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Really?? Awesome! I will test this solution as soon as I get home and mark this as the solution if it works.

Comment: Hmmm seems I'm on Version 40.0.2173.0 (64-bit)...